# Show content from DIV in a META-tag

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system, meta

I have a div which is like this:

```
            <div id="beskrivelse" class="description html_content" itemprop="description">
                {{description}}
            </div>
```

The content `{{description}}` is made in the backend.

How can I make it so that this content will be shown in my meta here:

```
            <meta property="og:description" content=" HERE "/>
```

I get a syntax error if I write:

```
            <meta property="og:description" content=" {{description}} "/>
```

Is ther a simple way to do it? Maybe put it in a variable of some sort?

There is no way for me to change this in the backend as I am using a closed system, Tictail.com.
I want what I have written in my `{{description}}` to be shown in the meta tag.

I cannot use any php, asp (etc) code as the site doesnt allow this.

Any suggestions?

---

I have tried this with no succes:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    var descval = document.getElementById('beskrivelse').innerHTML;
    var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for (i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
        var test = paras[i].getAttribute('property');
        if(test == "og:description")
        {
           paras[i].content = descval;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where in the document have you put your JavaScript? Make sure you place it at the bottom of the page, just before your closing `</body>`, or at least after the div containing the description, to make sure that the element is in the DOM when the script is executed. Also, do you have a meta-element with property `og:description` in your DOM from the beginning, or do you need to create it instead of searching for it?

Comment: I've put it in the bottom of the page before </body>. It doesnt change anything. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/vTtn2/

But if I can create one instead of changing the content it would fine with me. I'm not sure if the site will allow this as it creates its own meta when it cant find any.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, given that you already have a meta-element in you DOM with a property `og:description` and that you run you script either at the bottom of your page, or in a DOM-ready callback. As it does in your Fiddle, if you set the JS to be run onDomready (as I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vTtn2/4/)).

If you don't have the meta-element in the DOM from the beginning, you might need to create it and append it to the DOM. Something like this:

```
<script>
// Get the content
var descval = document.getElementById('beskrivelse').innerHTML;
// Create the new meta-element
var elm = document.createElement("meta");
elm.setAttribute("property", "og:description") 
elm.setAttribute("content", descval);
// Append the element to the HEAD
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elm);
</script>
```

Comment: Wierd. Whatever om trying it doesn't add or edit anything. Even on jsfiddle. 

The "<meta property="og:description" id="test" content=" HERE "/>" part doesnt change at all.

Even with the old code and the new code.

Comment: @user3760157 I have put it together in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTtn2/5/) and it does indeed work. Are you using the DOM-inspector of your browsers devtools, and not just "View source"? The source will never update, it contains only the content served by the server. You will have to use a developer-tool that keeps a live update of the current DOM in order to see the changes.

Comment: I think the problem is that the site creates the content after the javascript is activated. So it doesnt change anything, as the content is created afterwards and therefore nothing happens.