# Content from div as meta description

Tags: php, html, include, meta

I'm trying to get a content from a p element as a meta description.
I tried to adapt what I found here but no luck.
[Show content from DIV in a META-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360615/show-content-from-div-in-a-meta-tag)
What i have is a bunch of .php files with included header and footer like so.

```
<?php
 $title="Page title";
 include_once("/includes/header.php");
?>
<div class="container">
<p>This content i want in meta description and it's different in each php file.</p>
</div>
<?php
 include_once("/includes/bottom.php");
?>
```

What i want to achive is to have different meta descripiton for each .php page i have without editing hundred files (as i already did with the title...) but based on the content inside that paragraph using a script i can add to my header.php.

I tried to make that as clear as i could. Thank You in advance for all Your help.
EDIT
Where i want that description is in header.php

```
<meta name="description" content="This is where i want that description" />
```

Comment: meta description WHERE? in a `<meta>` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need PHP. With Javascript, you can retrieve the value of the paragraph tag, and then change the meta tag to have this value. Something like this:

```
<script>

var myText = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML

document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].setAttribute("content", myText);

</script>
```

Comment: Actually i found my job kinda pointless cause search engines don't run JS. Still much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

you could just inject the content stright into the tag, like this

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo someContent; ?>" />
```

(obviously you'd need to edit for the type of meta tag etc)

if you have the content on the server to put into a 'p' tag then it's a easy change to put it in the meta tag

Comment: No, the content that is inside 'p' tag is just there inside .php file like static html.

Comment: but I'm assuming you have the content you want on the php side?